# Max retries exceeded with url caused by NewConnectionError

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to crawl a product website with over 2000 products in a category for details like names etc over number of pages. However it breaks over time, over different links randomly with the above error.here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crawler1.py", line 103, in <module>
crawler(25)
File "crawler1.py", line 35, in crawler get_single_data(href)
File "crawler1.py", line 57, in get_single_data source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 71, in get return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 467, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.therealreal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products/women/handbags/handle-bags/chanel-lax-handle-bag-4 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10d8de190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',))
```

I have added delays every where i can think of using sleep by catching all errors. Is there a way to avoid this and can i pull all 2000 products data in one go.? or can anyone suggest a work around. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
try:
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
    sleep(.3)
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    print("1")
    sleep(30) 
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("2")
    sleep(30)
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
except ConnectionError:
    print("3")
    sleep(30)
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
except socket.error:
    sleep(30)
    source_code = requests.get(item_url, timeout=335)
plain_text  = source_code.text
temp = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
```

p.s You can ignore the timeouts i even tried none along with many values. Didn't help. What is going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you increase the timeout for the request? `...it breaks over time...` can be caused by the amount of requests the server has to deal with; the server gets more busy -> response takes a longer time -> request timeout

Comment: @dm295 technically keeping timeout none should help right, but even then i did increase it to 600 still it ran for about 700 products and the same error. How is it getting busy when i ask it to wait in for sometime?

Comment: @dcorelibran did you find solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

try catch  requests.exceptions.ConnectionError